# How to represent a 4 bit binary number with 8 bits in C#?

Tags: c#, binary

I tried to find an answer, but I couldn't formulate my question. So I'm trying to solve this problem. I have to represent a decimal number by its binary code, and I'm doing fine with the representation. I simple use `Convert.ToString(number, 2)`. However, if I enter 5 for example, the output on the console would be "101", but I prefer "00000101". I believe there should be a way of doing this, but I can't find any.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Convert.ToString(number, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');` should do it.